# Tool for converting stored procedures between Oracle<-> SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

What tools are you using to convert stored procedures/functions/triggers etc. between Oracle and SQL Server

Maybe somebody got a lint to "best practices" doc ? :)

Comment: pl/sql => t-sql or other way around?

Comment: Yes, that way  oracle->sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9DFB1773-5594-44A9-869F-A891629F80A5) this did the trick